# Is it okay to delete .dYSM file?

Tags: ios, swift, mastercard

I tried to submit a build in Test Flight, however, Apple rejects it because some of the libraries are using UIWebView, this includes Mastercard Payment Gateway (MPGSDK). It is using UIWebView in its .dYSM file. Is it okay to delete the .dYSM file containing the UIWebView?

I ran this

```
grep -r UIWebView /Path/To/Project/*

Binary file path/Carthage/Build/iOS/MPGSDK.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MPGSDK matches
```

Comment: You can delete the dsym file, but you will lose the ability to find the cause of crashes. Apple can still detect the use of the UIWebView though as the framework will link to that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can delete it, but you won't be able to analyze app crashes anymore.
Read more about the system here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html